# Need Help Handling a XML HTTP File Upload Request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, request

So, I looked up [a tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax) for uploading and sending files to a server with an XML HTTP Request. I followed the tutorial, however, I think I must be missing something. While the file appears to be uploaded and sent, nothing in the "handler" file is ever accessed. Is there a PHP function I need to write to process it? For context, here is what I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#upload-button').click(function(event)
    {
        $('#upload-button').removeClass("btn-danger");
    });

    $( "#report-form" ).submit(function( event )
    {

        var form = document.getElementById('report-form');
        var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select');
        var uploadButton = document.getElementById('upload-button');

        event.preventDefault(); // Stop the event from sending the way it usually does.

        uploadButton.value = 'Submitting...'; // Change text.
        var files = fileSelect.files;
        var maxfiles = <?php echo $config['Report_MaxFiles'] ?>;
        var mfs = <?php echo $config['Report_MaxFileSize'] ?>;
        if(files.length > maxfiles) // Make sure it's not uploading too many.
        {
            uploadButton.value = 'You uploaded too many files. The limit is ' + maxfiles + '.'; // Update button text.
            $('#upload-button').addClass('btn-danger'); // Make the button red, if so.
            return;
        }
        var formData = new FormData(); // Make a "form data" variable.
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];

            // Add the file to the request.
            if(file.size / 1000 > mfs)
            {
                uploadButton.value = 'One of the files is too big. The file size limit is ' + (mfs) + 'kb (' + (mfs / 1000) + 'mb).';
                $('#upload-button').addClass('btn-danger');
                return;
            }
            formData.append('files[]', file, file.name); // Not really sure what this does, to be honest,
                                                          // but I think it makes a file array.
        }

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Construct an XML HTTP Request
        xhr.open('POST', 'assets/class/FileHandler.php', true); // Open a connection with my handler PHP file.

        xhr.onload = function ()
        {
            if (xhr.status === 200)
            {
                uploadButton.value = 'Files Submitted!'; // NOTE: I do get this message.
            }
            else
            {
                uploadButton.value = 'An error occurred.';
                $('#upload-button').addClass("btn-danger");
            }
        };

        xhr.send(formData); // I think this is where it dies.
    });
});
```

At the "send(formData)" line, I'm not actually sure if it's sending. Do I set up some sort of listener in FileHandler.php that is activated when the files are sent via XML HTTP request? Or more specifically, how to I save the uploaded files to the server using my FileHandler.php file?

EDIT: I haven't been able to come up with any other PHP code in the FileHandler.php file than this, which I thought might be called when the form is sent (but it isn't):

EDIT 2: Okay, now I have something, but it isn't working (didn't expect it to). I think I may be using the variables wrong:

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'data/reports/uploads/' . $_POST['id'] . "/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['files']['name']);
echo "<script>console.log('RECEIVED');</script>";
echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";
```

It's not saving the file to the directory, nor is it printing the script message. How do I get my report.php file to execute these things in FileHandler.php?

Comment: What's your PHP code ?

Comment: That's just it: I don't have any.

Comment: You need some PHP to effectively save your file on server-side like the tutorial say: "Your server-side code will need to extract the files from the request and process them as desired."

Comment: Also I think `'THOU HAS SUMMONED ME?'` never appear in your console because you don't retrieve it from xhr object.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the question now is, once I send the form data, then what? I'm stumped as to how I'm supposed to extract the files from the request.

Comment: Check PHP doc: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php and there are good examples.

Comment: @Florian Lefèvre: I feel like I'm missing something. See my edits made in the original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74216/discussion-between-florian-lefevre-and-colonelhedgehog).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help and patience of @Florian Lefèvre, I got it fixed. :)

The problem was with the path. It wasn't locating the path to the folder data/uploads/ and wasn't making the directory. Here is what I did:

```
$uploaddir = '../../data/reports/uploads/' . $_POST['id'] . "/";
echo "NAME: " . $_FILES['files']['name'][0] . "\n";

foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $filenumber => $filename)
{
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename ($filename);

    echo "UploadDir " . $uploaddir . "\n";
    echo "UploadFile " . $uploadfile . "\n";
    echo '<pre>';

    echo "MKDir for UploadDir which is: ". $uploaddir . "\n";
    mkdir ($uploaddir);

    if (move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$filenumber], $uploadfile))
    {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }

    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';

    print "</pre>";
}

var_dump ($_FILES);
```

I haven't gotten rid of some of the debug stuff yet, but that's the general solution.